# Angular 2 form post to Laravel API and validate

Tags: angular, laravel-5, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I have been looking around to try and find a solution for this. does anyone have any example on how to post data from angular and have laravel validate the data and post back any errors or process and save... I can pretty much post the data to laravel but getting the responses back im struggling with trying to figure out how thats done.. any examples very appreciated

Comment: Share your code so that can suggest something which make sense. if you want to validate an Ajax Request please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation)